# io.crate.shade.org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: trust authentication failed for user "ABC"

Tags: postgresql, cratedb

I have a cratedb and i do have a ssh access to that machine . Lets say my username is ABC .

So i have written a spring boot code , which uses jooq and connects to the crate db to query .

Whenever i try to execute my query through my rest api  , Queries get formed and below error occurs

io.crate.shade.org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: trust authentication failed for user "ABC"

Question --> 
1.What do you mean by Trust ,
2.Is there anywhere in the cratedb i should add my username ?

Comment: looks like you're connecting via PSQL here and not REST?

default user is "crate" what happens if you do that? Re your 2nd question there are auth options for REST this might help https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/admin/auth/hba.html

Comment: I had forgot to add the user : crate in properties file . .. Thanks the issue is solved